# Database opens as read only

Tags: c#, database, windows, ms-access-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have installed the application of mine to the my computer and the other computer that are running on Windows 7 64 bit and all of the function are worked fine (adding the data to the database through system, delete a single data or clear all of the data from the database through system, edit the data in the database through system and look at whether the user has correct login username and password from the database through system).

But, when I installed the application of mine to the other computer that are running on Windows 7 32 bit, all of the functions not worked (object reference not set to the instance of the object when I want to adding the data to the database), but the user can login to the system (look at whether the user has correct login username and password from the database through system), but all of the functions except that (login to the system), are not worked, and when I open the database, the database has been opened as read-only. This problem has been bugged me, because I have been searching what's is the problem and cannot find the problem at all.

Anyone know what is the problem? Is it the operating system that restricted the database to be accessed by 64 bit only?

Thank you very much!

Your answer much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're missing the workgroup file?

Comment: the workgroup that have on when we connected to the internet? the other computer is offline sir (not connected to the internet when I installed my application to there, Windows 32 bit)

Comment: @Kaoru worgroup file for the database.  Access uses workgroup files along with the main database files to store permissions and user credentials.  I had a similar issue approximately eight months ago, because I forgot to include a workgroup file in my connection string.